# Method nonvisibility of same instanceof but differing class

Tags: java, class, methods, visibility

I have something like the below:

```
Item var;
```

Depending on user input, it will be initialized as a different class:

```
if (/*user input*/ == 1) {
    var = new Item();
} else {
    var = new Truck();
}
```

The classes are defined as:

```
public class Truck extends Item {
    public void someMethod();
    public void exclusiveMethod();
}
public class Item {
    public void someMethod();
}
```

Note `Truck` has an exclusive method, `exclusiveMethod()` that `Item` does not have. Depending on some conditions, a series of methods will be called on `var`:

```
// will only return true if var was initialized as Truck
if (/*conditions*/) {
    var.someMethod();
    var.exclusiveMethod();
} else {
    var.someMethod();
}
```

Netbeans pops up an error that `exclusiveMethod()` cannot be found because it is not in `Item`. I need method visibility of `exclusiveMethod()` only when `var` was initialized as `Truck`. I have some constraints, though: `Item var;` must be in my code before other logic, and I cannot create an interface which I then implement in both `Item` and `Truck`. I also cannot modify `public class Item{}` at all.

What can I do?

Comment: Please refer Java inheritance

Comment: You can't call a method of a `Truck` on an `Item`, you'll have to use [casting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: Put the code that contains this if-statement inside a method in the class `Item`. And *override* that method inside the class `Truck`  and implement it differently there (also call `exclusiveMethod`). And read up on object-oriented programming, that will explain why this is the right approach.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, I cannot modify class `Item`: no adding or editing.

Comment: Simply put, you want to call either of the method conditionally - check your object with `instanceof` as suggested in both of the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection APIs to call the `exclusiveMethod` .

The code would look something like -

```
Method m = var.getClass().getMethod("exclusiveMethod", null);
if(m != null) {
    m.invoke(var, null);
}
```

You can get more information about relfection APIs here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

---

Another way to get this is by casting the `var` onto a `Truck` , if you are sure that var is an object of type `Truck` . the example code for that would be -

```
if(var instanceof Truck) {
    ((Truck)var).exclusiveMethod()
}
```

Comment: The cast option is better

Comment: Yes, I just gave all the options possible.

Answer (score 2):

As from you question I understand that if the user input is say 1 then the `var` would be instantiated as `Truck` else it should be instantiated as `Item`. The code is workable. I feel you have a problem while calling the method `exclusiveMethod()` you could check the instance by using `instanceof` and then call the method as below:

```
if (var instanceof Truck) {
    var.someMethod();
    ((Truck)var).exclusiveMethod();
} else {
    var.someMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basic OOP polymorphism. Define an empty exclusiveMethod() in your superclass (Item) and then override it in Truck adding some code. You won't need any if statements or class checks.

```
public class Item {
    public void someMethod() {
       // do something
    }

    public void exclusiveMethod() {
    }
}

public class Truck extends Item {
    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
       // do something else
    }

    @Override
    public void exclusiveMethod() {
       // implement me
    }
}

...

Item item = getItemOrTruck(...);
item.someMethod();
item.exclusiveMethod();
```